# Swift package error while importing firebase as a dependency

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I am creating a custom swift package that depends on firebase. I followed different tutorial but I struggling with an error.

This is my package description:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "FirebaseAuthManagment",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "FirebaseAuthManagment",
            targets: ["FirebaseAuthManagment"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git", from: "9.6.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "FirebaseAuthManagment",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "Firebase")
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "FirebaseAuthManagmentTests",
            dependencies: ["FirebaseAuthManagment"]),
    ]
)
```

This is the error `unknown package 'Firebase' in dependencies of target 'FirebaseAuthManagment'; valid packages are: 'firebase-ios-sdk'`. The Package name is `FirebaseAuthManagment`.

The problem is on the product specification `.product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "Firebase")`. If this line is avoided I can find different Firebase packages like `FirebaseStorage`, `FirebaseAnalytics` and others but not `FirebaseAuth`.